# Unable to connect to oracle with different OS user accout

Tags: oracle, ubuntu-12.04

I have installed Oracle on Ubuntu with OS user `oracle`. When I try to connect to Oracle when logged on as different OS user (other than `oracle`), I get error:

```
SQL> connect user1/user1@orcl 
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

However, if I don't mention Oracle SID then I don't get any error:

```
SQL> connect user1/user1
Connected to:
Oracle Database 
SQL>
```

I have declared `ORACLE_HOME` and `SID` in the user profile. But it did not work. Can someone please help me to understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In a sense you don't really have a problem; you can connect locally using the `ORACLE_HOME` and `ORACLE_SID` environment variables, which is fine.

When you use the `connect user1/user1@orcl` version, the `orcl` is *not* your SID; as explained in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve015.htm) it is an 'Oracle Net connect identifier'.

> *connect_identifier*
>
> An Oracle Net connect identifier. The exact syntax depends on the
>   Oracle Net configuration. For more information, refer to the Oracle
>   Net manual or contact your DBA. SQL*Plus does not prompt for a service
>   name, but uses your default database if you do not include a connect
>   identifier.

So you are connecting over a network connection, even though its to the same host, rather than internally using IPC. You don't even need to have `ORACLE_SID` set when you do that, because that is used for IPC and isn't part of the network connection.

Now, the connect identifier may well actually be the same string as your SID, but it doesn't have to be. Usually when you're using a single term like `orcl` you're using a 'net service name' which is defined in your `tnsnames.ora` file. (Depending on how the [naming methods are configured in your `sqlnet.ora`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/glossary.htm#BGBIDIII), which determines how the connect identifier is resolved; but this is still the most common configuration I think).

The Oracle Net configuration can be configured using the [`netca`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10836/glossary.htm#BGBIFGDG) configuration assistant, as the `oracle` user, though you can create a private `tnsnames.ora` to override that.

See the [Oracle Net admin guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10836/intro.htm) for more about how connectivity works and is configured, and the [SQL*Plus user guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_three.htm#i1142625) for a shorter version.

In order for your `user1/user1@orcl` connection to work you would need a `tnsnames.ora` entry looking something like:

```
orcl = 
 (DESCRIPTION = 
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=my_host)(PORT=1521))
   (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)))
```

... where `my_host` is the DNS name or IP address of your Oracle server, and `1521` is the port the listener is configured to run on. (The listener has to be running for you to be able to connect this way, too). The `SERVICE_NAME` is not necessarily the same as your SID either, but depends on the database configuration; the `lsnrctl status` command will show what service names are available.

The ORA-12154 error is telling you that you either don't have a `tnsnames.ora` file at all, or that it doesn't contain an entry for the alias `orcl`.

As @a_horse_with_no_name points out, there are other forms of connect identifier, and you don't necessarily need a `tnsnames.ora` file for a network connection; the options are [explained here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10836/concepts.htm#CIAGGGDG). I've just focused on the one you were trying to use. You don't necessarily need to use any of them though since you are able to connect locally.

Comment: One thing that might be worth mentioning: you can get away without having a `tnsnames.ora` by putting the using the complete connect string on the commandline (after the `@`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - indeed, but it was already long and rambling (and confusing) enough so I was just focusing on the method the OP had tried to use. I've added a link to the alternatives - thanks.